# How can someone sell their Pokemon Go account?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have seen on some sites that you can purchase a Pokemon Go account. But if we cannot reassign the account to another person or link it to a different email, how is this possible?

How can someone sell their account?

Answer (score 9):

They likely can't do this without violating Pokemon Go's [Terms of Service](https://nianticlabs.com/terms/en/):

> #### 6 Conduct, General Prohibitions, and Niantic’s Enforcement Rights
>
> ...In addition, you agree not to do any of the following, unless applicable law mandates that you be given the right to do so:...
>
> - use the Services or Content, or any portion thereof, for any commercial purpose or in a manner not permitted by these Terms, including but not limited to... **(c) selling, reselling, or renting the Apps or your Account;**...

Emphasis mine. Unless the sellers (and potentially buyers) are in a jurisdiction with a law allowing transfer of accounts, it is against Niantic's terms of service to do so, and Niantic outlays that they can terminate an account for stuff like this:

> Although Niantic is not obligated to monitor access to or use of the Services or Content or to review or edit any Content, we have the right to do so for the purpose of operating the Services, to ensure compliance with these Terms, and to comply with applicable law or other legal requirements. **We reserve the right to remove or disable access to any Content, at any time and without notice.** Niantic may remove any Content we consider to be objectionable or in violation of these Terms. We have the right to investigate violations of these Terms or conduct that affects the Services.

My advice? Stay well clear of anyone selling access to accounts in this manner. Even if the seller is on the level, Niantic may decide to simply disable the account entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Although against the Terms of Service, the seller can sell their account by giving out the email address along with the login credentials. The buyer can then log in and get the progress of the account.

This can be shady business though, as the account can be retrieved by the seller by using "Forget Password" or other ways of logging in, then the seller can change the password and lock the buyer out of the account.